# How to solve parse error while installing an apk?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I've created an app using Xamarin forms and I'm trying to run it on an Android device.

Initially it did not have any android background services and it installed correctly on my phone and worked fine.
After adding 2 background services to it, I get Parse Error : "There was a problem parsing the package." while installing it on phone. However, it works correctly on the emulator.

Can anyone help in solving this issue ???

Comment: Have you tried to uncheck the `Use fast deployment` at the project properties? It looks like junk files or cache in the `obj`/`bin` folders or in the device itself.

Comment: Nope. will do it. But its quite strange. It fails only when I add android  background service in it. without android background service, it works fine !!!

Comment: Nope no errors. It works correct on emulator...Targeting 8.0. But if I try to change the target framework to lower than 7.0 it shows lot of errors while building :(

Comment: I'm out of ideas now =/

Comment: Sorry your comment got removed by mistake...

Comment: No. I did it. It became irrelevant and unnecessary once it's not the cause of problem =)